# SOCKET.io not listening on a port

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a script referring to socket.io on port 3000 which it should be listening to. However when running the code I get the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` the same thing happens when I try and access the URL it says this:
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This error also pops up on my heroku app. So can someone help me?

Here is my server code

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500;
const INDEX = '/index.html';

const server = express()

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`))

server.use(express.static("public"))

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`)
})


const users = {}

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('new-user', name => {
    users[socket.id] = name
    if(name == "null"){
        socket.broadcast.emit('null-user', name)
        delete users[socket.id]
    }else{
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', name)
    }
  })
  socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', { message: message, name: users[socket.id] })
  })
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id])
    delete users[socket.id]
  })
})
```

And my client-side code

```
const messageContainer = document.getElementById('message-container')
const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')

const name = prompt('What is your name?')
appendMessage('You joined')
socket.emit('new-user', name)

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
  appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`)
})

socket.on('user-connected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} connected`)
})

socket.on('user-disconnected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} disconnected`)
})

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const message = messageInput.value
  appendMessage(`You: ${message}`)
  socket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
  messageInput.value = ''
})

function appendMessage(message) {
  const messageElement = document.createElement('div')
  messageElement.innerText = message
  messageContainer.append(messageElement)
}
```

Comment: perhaps your code is doing something wrong

Comment: I already checked that possibility but I have added my code just in case

Comment: By default, your code is using port 5500, so I'm not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: socket.io and express should be using the same port however Im unsure on how to go about doing that and still when I remove all the express code the error still shows meaning that it cannot be express issue. The issue here is that socket.io(node package) should be listening on 3000 but nothing is listening on that port. It doesn't appear to be listening on 5500 either

Comment: you neglected to show how the client is making the connection

Comment: In the first line, you arent giving socket.io a port `const io = require('socket.io')();`, you need to put the listening port into the second set of parentheses, like `const io = require('socket.io')(3000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);


    http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
    });
```

Try this. It uses both express and SocketIO on the same port